# How to compare the current member value with previous member value in mdx query?

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

I am having the following data in my `SSAS` cube

[image]

I need to get the value based on a comparison between the current value and the previous value using `MDX` query.

In this example data, I need to get the `Weight` value as `Result` when the current value of `Id` column is not equal to the previous value of `Id` column otherwise 0.

Please find the formula and the sample result in the below screenshot for reference.
[image]

I have tried to achieve the requirement using [PrevMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/prevmember-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15) function available in the `Mdx` but it is not working.

Please find the query I have tried:

```
WITH     MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS IIF([Id].CURRENTMEMBER = [Id].CURRENTMEMBER.PrevMember,0,[Weight])  
SELECT{ [Measures].[Expression1]} ON COLUMNS ,
NONEMPTY((TOPCOUNT( (Order((([class].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS)),[class].[Id].CurrentMember.MemberValue,ASC)),101)),
{ [Measures].[Expression1]}) ON ROWS FROM [Model] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

The result am getting for the query is

[image]